# Custom Permission enforced in an Activity and added as Intent Filter

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have read and checked how to do this online and on books but it won't work on my Note 3. This is what I did.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hardkore.testapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="com.hardkore.permissions.MY_PERMISSION"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
    android:label="@string/perm_label"
    android:description="@string/perm_desc" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:permission="com.hardkore.permissions.MY_PERMISSION"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.hardkore.permissions.MY_PERMISSION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

this is the error that logcat displayed

```
02-15 16:21:32.525: W/ActivityManager(807): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
02-15 16:21:32.525: W/ActivityManager(807): Permission Denial: starting Intent {       
act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000   cmp=com.hardkore.testapp/.MainActivity 
} 
from null (pid=28305, uid=2000) requires com.hardkore.permissions.MY_PERMISSION
02-15 16:21:35.525: W/ActivityManager(807): mDVFSHelper.release()
```

Comment: It seems to be working as it should, doesn't it? A component that does not have your custom permission is trying to start your protected activity, and gets denied.

Comment: That is what I don't understand. When I comment out the permission within the activity and also the intent filter. The app works.

Answer (score 3):

After declaring a custom permission in the manifest file, you should also declare that your application is using this permission. This seems redundant, but it worked for me.

```
<permission
    android:name="com.hardkore.permissions.MY_PERMISSION"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
    android:label="@string/perm_label"
    android:description="@string/perm_desc" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.hardkore.permissions.MY_PERMISSION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid defining a custom permission for your MAIN activity. The android framework is not having that permission and as a result, it won't be able to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Your putting a custom permission on your main launcher activity ...How can android start this activity now ?  Remove the custom permission or make another main activity.

Answer (score 0):

**try calling the activity like**

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent .setAction("com.hardkore.permissions.MY_PERMISSION");
            intent .addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            startActivity(intent );
```

> And don't forget to add the permission in your other app like

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.hardkore.permissions.MY_PERMISSION"/>
```